# BaseStream underlying stream

Tags: c#, stream

I was trying to read a binary file, it was written in a certain pattern for example: `string, string, byte`

I surfed web and found  this code:

```
while (br.BaseStream.Position<br.BaseStream.Length)
{
    br.ReadString();
    br.ReadString();
    br.ReadByte(); 
}
```

Even though it is easy code I can't understand what the underlying stream(BaseStream) means? Can somebody give me a brief explanation of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.NET offers different objects to read or write data. Basicly there are DataWriters and DataReaders that write or read into different streams. [Streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_%28computing%29) are representing the data flow between the data source (e.g. a file) to your applications memory (or back).

To access the stream in a defined direction you can use readers or writers. `BinaryReader` is one example of an data reader. It is supposed to read binary data out of the stream. Streams usually inherit from a base class called `Stream`. There are different type of streams representing different data sources. For example a `FileStream` reads or writes data into a file on the HDD, whereas a `MemoryStream` reads or writes data into the RAM. So the implementation of a stream describes **where the data is stored**.

DataReaders or DataWriters describe **how the data is stored**. For example your `BinaryReader` reads byte sequences, whereas a `TextReader` reads text with a given encoding. But both can be used with the same stream.

To come back to your question: Your `BinaryReader` reads binary data from a stream. The `BaseStream` property returns the instance of the stream the reader reads data from. This is why you need to initialize the `BinaryReader` with an stream instance. You cannot tell the computer to read binary data from nowhere! ;)